# Prometheus in Grafana, how to time shift single query backwards

Tags: prometheus, grafana

What does not work:

- Grafana's time shift option because it applies to all queries, and negative values not accepted.
- Adding 'offset' to the query allows to move it forward (to the right) in time, but a negative value is not accepted.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Since 2.48.0<sup>1</sup> you may use [offset modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier) in promQL. However, this will give you the right data with wrong (or confusing, because time offset is not applied to) timestamp.

---

<sup>1</sup> : This was also available since 2.26.0, but only with additional flag `--enable-feature=promql-negative-offset`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this feature request](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/10395) there is a workaround for time shifts "into future".

Instead of something like `-1h` use `0h+1h`.